# How to save twitterscraper output as json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I read the documentation, but the documentation only mentions saving output as `.txt` file. I tried to modify the code to save output as JSON.

save as `.txt`:

```
from twitterscraper import query_tweets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_tweets = query_tweets("Trump OR Clinton", 10)

    #print the retrieved tweets to the screen:
    for tweet in query_tweets("Trump OR Clinton", 10):
        print(tweet)

    #Or save the retrieved tweets to file:
    file = open(“output.txt”,”w”)
    for tweet in query_tweets("Trump OR Clinton", 10):
        file.write(tweet.encode('utf-8'))
    file.close()
```

I tried to modify this to save as JSON:

```
 output = query_tweets("Trump OR Clinton", 10)
 jsonfile = open("tweets.json","w")
    for tweet in output:
        json.dump(tweet,jsonfile)
    jsonfile.close()

TypeError: Object of type Tweet is not JSON serializable
```

But I get the above type error

How can I save output as JSON?
I know that typing command in termminal creates JSON, but I wanted to write a python version.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to convert each tweet to a dict first, as Python class objects are not serializable as JSON. Looking at the first object we can see the available methods and attributes like this: `help(list_of_tweets[0])`. Accessing the `__dict__` of the first object we see:

```
# print(list_of_tweets[0].__dict__)
{'user': 'foobar',
'fullname': 'foobar',
'id': '143846459132929',
'url': '/foobar/status/1438420459132929',
'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 5, 23, 59, 53),
'text': 'blah blah',
'replies': 0,
'retweets': 0,
'likes': 0,
'html': '<p class="TweetTextSize...'}
```

Before we can dump it to json we'll need to convert the `datetime` objects to strings.

```
tweets = [t.__dict__ for t in list_of_tweets]
for t in tweets:
    t['timestamp'] = t['timestamp'].isoformat()
```

Then we can use the json module to dump the data to a file.

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(tweets, f)
```